# TCPDF Side by Side Table

Tags: php, html-table, inline, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to print some document record. But my second table will always next to the bottom of the first table (just like the image). I need to make the second is on the left side of the first table. Any code warrior please ... :)

[image]

Here's my code so far ...

[image]

Comment: There is not much space to show both the table side by side.Put a parent table with two column & try to put both the table in those columns with a min width for testing.

Comment: already tried that, man ... Still have the same issue

Comment: You should paste the actual code into the question and not use an image of the code please. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4370109

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a table side-by-side, you have to create a parent table where the width is 100% and the one pair of "tr" and 2 pairs of "td" and, on each of "td" make another table. Here is the draft:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        // Left side Table
        <td width="50%">
            <table width="100%" border="1">
                <tr><td>Data goes here</td></tr>
            </table>    
        </td>

        // Right side Table
        <td width="50%">
            <table width="100%" border="1">
                <tr><td>Data goes here</td></tr>
            </table>   
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It seems your using writeHTML per group, why not just use one and apply the parent table with two child table, you just have to use concat.

Comment: wow ... tables inside table ... AWESOME!! Thanks dude!
Never thought about it!

Comment: what if we using `for` loop? The height of two tables mismatch. Any solution for that?!?!

Comment: @Kirataka I recommend using MultiCell with that kind of problem